# how to make a automation testing framework

Tags: maven, selenium, frameworks, testng, browser-automation

I have to make a framework for my organization for the selenium automation testing.currently we works on test-ng integrated with eclipse with the maven.Now for this we have to make a huge setup in every project. Also now we are planning to involve the manual testers in the automaton but it wont be easy for them to set up these kinds of things.So can we make a framework like in which only have to add test-cases only nothing else. i know these kind of stuffs are being used by some organizations but i dont know anything about this. Can anybody suggest me any thing on this.
Like from where we can start and some kind of sample work etc
Any kind of help would be welcomed
Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start from writing stories/examples by testers using something like jbehave and automate them. Or using frameworks like http://selenide.org/